# Associatif array doesnt have a length

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to **JSON.stringify** an associatif array in javascript, when i console.log it the output is :

```
Array[0]
adresse:
"zfzf"
adresse2:
"zfz"
adresse3:
"fzfz"
code_postal
"fzfz"
[...]
length:
0
[...]
__proto__:
Array[0]
```

as you can see the **lenght** is equal to **0**, so when i JSON.Strigify it, the answer is **[ ]**

i use to build my array like this :

```
var info = [];
    $("[data-change]").each(function(key,obj){
        if ($(obj).val() == "") {
            i = 1;
        }
        else {
            info[$(obj).attr("name")] = $(obj).val();
            j++;
        }
    });
```

all those "data-change" are inputs, i've tryied to use the variable **j** instead of **$(obj).attr("name")]** and it works but i neeed the key to be the name of the input

Comment: Make it javascript object. Use `info = {};`, then create your object and then stringify it. You're at this point is creating an array, which don't have `$(obj).attr("name")]` index. That's why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Because Objects doesn't have `length` property.

Use `Object.keys(obj).length` to view length